# PureFTPD Kloxo Error

Tags: centos, admin, kloxo, pureftpd

I am trying to run kloxo on a OpenVZ VPS. Kloxo is supposed to use PureFTPD for the FTP Server. When I attempt to connect from localhost, or remotely using filezilla or even net2ftp on a proxy, I get the same result...

```
    [root@srv1 /]# ftp localhost
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1).
    Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -A -c50 -B -C8 -D -fftp -H -I15 -lpam -L10000:8 -m4 -s -                     
    U133:022 -u500 -i -Oclf:/var/log/pureftpd.log -k99 -Z
    ftp>
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Also, I cannot locate the Log Files.

CenOS Version: CentOS release 5.9 (Final) Kloxo Version: 6.1.12

---

It won't let me answer, but I have the answer...http://forum.lxcenter.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=74468&

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Kloxo. In order to make FTP working again, run the following commands as a root:

```
yum –y downgrade pure-ftpd 
/script/upcp 
/script/cleanup 
yum -y update
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Tried this and after I tried testing the connection using the command `ftp localhost` and I got this response `Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1).
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection`

Comment: After following your steps then using the file located at the site below, I was able to get things working. http://ronelnevarez.com/error-pure-ftpd-symbol-my_make_scrambled_password/

Answer (score 0):

First of check if ftp is running on server as below:

/etc/init.d/pureftpd status

or

ps -aufx |grep ftp

if it running then check if port 21 is listening with telnet:

telnet localhost 21